# Unable to open pdf file in adobe reader

Tags: pdf, adobe

I have PDF file which is opening in all browsers but unable to open in adobe.
I am using macOS ventura version 13.4
using latest adobe
please find file[pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X51O0v2eLmU94pfcFPXj3i8cJ6SZ1riI/view?usp=drive_link)